# Is there a way to send Keys to the Windowmanager

Tags: ruby, linux, archlinux, dwm

Is there a gem to send keys to the Windowmanager with Ruby?
I would like to send commands to the windowmanager (I use dwm). Something like

```
windowmanager.send( "MOD-Shift-C" )
```

or stuff would be great.

Answer (score 2):

It hasn't been updated in a while, but try the `xdo` gem:

- http://rubygems.org/gems/xdo
- http://auto.rubyforge.org/xdo/index.html
- https://github.com/Quintus/Automations/tree/master/xdo

Answer (score 2):

This question is also partially answered by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1446617), which gives examples for Windows and for Mac. [echristopherson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10566573) is for Linux only, which does seem to be what you are referring to.